# How can I count the number of rows in a table using a procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't seem to crack this one, I will appreciate your assistance!

I'm willing to write a stored procedure that receives a table name (string) and if the table exists, then the procedure should print the number of rows in the table, otherwise, it should print "-1".

I've tried the next code both it keeps printing "-1" even though the procedure is being applied to existing tables:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_pro (@Table_Name varchar(50))

AS

BEGIN

IF OBJECT_ID ('@Table_Name') IS NOT NULL

SELECT COUNT(*)

FROM CONCAT('dbo.', @Table_Name) AS num_rows

ELSE PRINT '-1'

END

 
EXEC test_pro training_kehila

 
-- Dropping the procedure
IF OBJECT_ID ('test_pro') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE test_pro
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might supply `training_kehila` to the stored procedure but it will always be checking if a table named `@Table_Name` exists. To measure the actual row count you'll need dynamic SQL.

Comment: google: "dynamic sql"

Answer (score 1):

Well:

```
OBJECT_ID ('@Table_Name')
```

Should be:

```
OBJECT_ID (@Table_Name)
```

But that won't help, because you still can't say `FROM @Table_Name`.

This is the wrong approach anyway (counting all of the rows in the table). Number of rows in a table is accessible via a simple call to the metadata, which will make a massive difference in performance as your tables get bigger, and which doesn't require dynamic SQL at all.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test_pro 
   @Table_Name nvarchar(128) -- not varchar(50)!
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT NumberOfRows = COALESCE(c, -1)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT c = SUM(rows)
    FROM sys.partitions
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(CONCAT(N'dbo.', QUOTENAME(@Table_Name)))
      AND index_id IN (0,1)
  ) AS s;
END
```

And then to call it:

```
EXEC dbo.test_pro @Table_Name = N'training_kehila';
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1vscjCO1).